# Android getInputStream Isn't Working Properly

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a method for getting the altitude of a place from the website:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=0,0 (where the 0,0 can be replaced with any coordinates).

However, I got a problem when getting the `InputStream` from the URL connection.

```
private double altitude(double lat, double longi) {
    String elevation = "";
    try {
        URL alt = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations="+lat+","+longi);
        HttpURLConnection altFind = (HttpURLConnection) alt.openConnection();
        altFind.setDoInput(true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(altFind.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        OUT:
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (inputLine.contains("elevation")) {
                for (int i = 23; ; i++) {
                    if (inputLine.charAt(i) != ',') {
                        elevation = elevation + "" + inputLine.charAt(i);
                    } else {
                        break OUT;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(elevation);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {}
    catch (IOException e) {}
    return 0;
}
```

That is the method and I call it from here:

```
private TextView t;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener listener;
double elev;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String longlat = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    longlat = longlat.replaceAll(" ", "");
    String [] longilati = longlat.split(",");
    final double [] coord = new double[2];
    coord[0] = Double.parseDouble(longilati[0]);
    coord[1] = Double.parseDouble(longilati[1]);

    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        elev = altitude(coord[0], coord[1]);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No connection available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I've tried following similar questions to no avail.

Comment: Please define "isnt working properly". Do you get an error? Does it crash? What is unexpected?

Comment: `I'm getting a problem with getting the InputStream from the URL connection.`. Which problem?

Comment: You will have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. And your app is crashing. You should have told that all!

Comment: `catch (MalformedURLException e) {}
    catch (IOException e) {}`. You you are leaving those catch blocks empty!? Instead of putting code in it to get the cause and to inform the user.

Comment: when I run it on my phone it crashes the programme

Answer (score 1):

You should perform Network Connections on Background Thread.

You can use `Asynctask` class and move `altitude` method inside `doInBackground()`.

You can read more here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

EDITED:

I found this class called `JSONParser` which I think this is what you need, check this out:
https://gist.github.com/dmnugent80/b2e22e5546c4b1c391ee

Copy and paste it into your project.

You can modify your `altitude` method by calling `makeHttpRequest` method from `JSONParser` class and passing all the parameters needed. If you do it right, then the method will return JSON object from the URL. For example:

```
private static final String URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json";
private static final String METHOD = "GET"; // You can use POST either

private double altitude(double lat, double lng) {
    double elevation = 0.0;
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("locations", lat + "," + lng);
    // Here you can put another params if needed

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, METHOD, params);

    if(jsonObject != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.toString()); // Check if data has arrived safely?

        try {
            JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(0);
            elevation = result.getDouble("elevation");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return elevation;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Call `altitude` inside `doInBackground` and see the result.

Comment: I've tried to add this but it hasn't worked. Though I may have done it wrong

Comment: I have problems executing the method using the code in the link

Comment: @JoshuaTurner I have edited my answer, hope this help you.